# Use Canvas toDataUrl to save dom elements to an image

Tags: javascript, canvas

Using Javascript and Canvas with this:

```
canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

What can one save with this? Ie. Can I utilise this to save a set of dom elements, with their styling to an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`canvas.toDataURL("image/png");` will only save what is currently on the canvas.

You could save a screenshot of your webpage using a library such as [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), but on its own canvas cannot save dom elements and style info.

Basically think of it as paintbrush or any other image editing application, when you hit file, save as png, you save what is currently on the canvas as a png, same thing applies to the `canvas` element.